# Replace javascript variable without id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this javascript and once the AJAX process is executed I want to replace this variable to some other variable.

```
window.onload = function() {
  oldvariable = [];
  var chart = new Chart("Container2", {
    data: [{
      type: "column",
      dataPoints: oldvariable
    }]
  });
}
```

When I process the AJAX request and fetch JSON data which is stored in oldvariable, it is not written so I have few options. I tried ads they are working in HTML but not under script tag.

If I can define `oldvariable='<div class="second"></div>';` and replace this with processed JSON data then it is working and giving correct output in HTML but in javascript `<` tag is not allowed as variable so we cant define oldvariable like that.

```
$( "div.second" ).replaceWith( ''+newvariable +'' );
```

So is there anyway I can replace javascript variable as HTML tags are not allowed in variable and without tag javascript can't replace.

I have one more probable solution.regex. Search for oldvariable in entire HTML code and replace with  newvariable  but that process will be very slow so what is the best way to do this.

My vairables are globally defined and AJAX request is in external file and above codes are embeded in HTML.

========edit

how we can replace oldvariable with newvariable in above javascript

====== ajax code- variable name is different

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        $('#upload-form2').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data) {
                var oldvariable = '',
                    downlo;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    downlo = data[i];
                    oldvariable += '' + downlo.ndchart + '';
                }
              $('#chek').html(oldvariable );
               }
        })
    })();
  });
```

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble working out exactly what you're asking here...

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is "This variable" referring to?

Comment: where is ajax code ? please specify little more about the issue.

Comment: @Clonkex revising the question

Comment: i think you need to update the chart based on ajax response data isn't it ? @swetlana

Comment: @JYoThI  yes absolutely

Comment: show your ajax part @swetlana

Comment: One doesn't *replace* variables, one assigns new values to them. You're trying to go about this the wrong way, you should be updating (or deleting and re-adding) the chart from within the Ajax success handler, not trying to treat the JS source code as a string to be manipulated. Please [edit] your question to show the relevant Ajax code.

Comment: @JYoThI ajax code added

Comment: @nnnnnn ajax part added

Comment: can you check my below answer @swetlana and show the response data .what is inisde the data . ?

Comment: @JYoThI ajax js file is http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/js/script721.js

Comment: check my update 1 @swetlana

Comment: @JYoThI 
i have embeded your success code in html page . not in external js here is full code pastebin.com/APtDnaeF

Comment: i gave you code for ajax success part only you need to embed it with your ajax function . but your not doing that . @swetlana

Comment: @JYoThI you want in external js file or embed in html script  ? have already embeded in html but its giving error.

Comment: check my update 2 .i did some modification check it again @swetlana

Comment: @JYoThI thx for ur help. seems almost done but getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined for this line             chart.options.data[0].dataPoints=new_data;

Comment: comment these chart.options.data[0].dataPoints=new_data;
                    chart.render();  two line and print the data object like this console.log(chart.options.data);

Comment: @JYoThI because of this undefined reason i was embeding in html script .                 console.log(chart.options.data);
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined . i think best way will be replace the variable after success and append the value in main html with jquery replace

Comment: @JYoThI thanks for your help,. i will update by end of day. i am 99% sure i will make it. your help is 100% and will accept answer once done. thx again

Comment: sorry .really hard to understand your problem . explain bit more with your specific problem and update your post with exact code . @swetlana

Comment: @JYoThI make it working with ur help. would love to buy one flower if u like flowers. thanks again

Comment: glad to help you @swetlana stay in touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to update `chart datapoints` and `re-render` the chart after ajax success  like this

**ajax :**

```
    ...

    success:function(response)
    {
        chart.options.data[0].dataPoints=response;

        //response is (array) of dataSeries

        chart.render();
    }

   .......
```

**update 1 :** As per your code data should be updated like this

```
.....
success:function(data) {

            var new_data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
            {
                new_data.push({y:data[i].ndchart });
            }

            chart.options.data[0].dataPoints=new_data;
            chart.render();
         }
  .....
```

**update 2**:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
    (function() {
        $('#upload-form2').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data) {

                   var new_data = [];
                   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                   {
                      new_data.push({y:data[i].ndchart });
                    }

                    chart.options.data[0].dataPoints=new_data;
                    chart.render();

               }
        })
    })();
  });
```

Comment: getting error compress-jpeg:748 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: i have embeded your success code in html page . not in external js here is full code https://pastebin.com/APtDnaeF